# Scrub radius increase when changing wheel offset

Tags: toyota, tires

2019 4Runner Limited came with 245/60/20 Yokohama Geolandar O96B tires. I replaced the original 20-inch wheel with Toyota's 7x17 TRD wheel, and the offset changed from 15 to 4. Now I am changing the tires to General Grabber ATX LT245/75/17. One online calculator estimates that I will increase scrub radius by 1 5/32”. Not sure how reliable that online website is

https://www.wheel-size.com/calc/?wheel1=245-60-20X7.5ET15&wheel2=245-75-17X7ET4&fcl=2in&wcl=1.25in&scl=2in&sr=0in

but, if it is accurate, will I damage the vehicle? I've tried a Continental LT245/75/17, so I know there's no rub, but I don't really understand implications of scrub radius.

Comment: I should have added that when I replaced the original 20-inch wheel with Toyota's 7x17 TRD wheel, the offset changed from 15 to 4.

Comment: I'd recommend that you edit that into your question, because it's a very important detail!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all my resources with me to check right now (because quite frankly, scrub radius is pretty easy to confuse), but **the short answer** to whether this change in scrub radius will damage your vehicle is **no, it won't.**

To put it succinctly, scrub radius is the distance between the center of your contact patch and the intersection of the steering axis on the ground surface. The interaction between these two points works like this: any (longitudinal) frictional forces that act on your tires (ie. acceleration and braking) **will result in a moment around the steering axis**, and can affect stability and handling characteristics under certain conditions. In simpler terms, whenever you accelerate or brake, **the friction of the tires will try to make them turn inwards** (towards each other) **or outwards**, depending on the scrub radius. Therefore, a change in scrub radius will affect this behaviour.

Generally speaking, you won't damage your car by changing your scrub radius. It also typically doesn't have a significant effect on tire or suspension wear. However, as you've already done, checking whether your new wheels will fit on your car without interfering with the fenders or suspension components is important to ensure there won't be any problems. As an aside, I'll see if I can add some pictures as they make this topic a lot easier to understand.

Further reading: [Racing Aspirations - What is Scrub Radius](https://www.racingaspirations.com/scrub-radius/)